Crystal report and Merge document feature is not working in windows 11 but the same build works fine in windows 10
I had developed a windows desktop application in .NET C# which is running over 8 years and now we have recently upgraded to the latest framework with 4.6 and also upgraded the crystal report to 13 with 64 bit. All the features are working fine in windows 10 but the same build doesn't working in windows 11.
While opening the crystal report the application crashes and the merge document throws an error as like attached. Sign mismatch error Unable to cast object type
Kindly, let us know what code changes do we need to do to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.
I would like to know what are the changes require to do to resolve this.

What is a "Merge document"?
Is the exception thrown just by loading an rpt file?
Or is it while merging the output of multiple rpt files (e.g. doing a PDF Merge)?
